How to smoothly move a card
I'm trying to move a card programmatically and very smoothly (the third one) to the top of the viewport onclick event, but am having trouble doing so.
I can manage an instantaneous move (but not a smooth one) apparently, or a smooth one which does not move to the top of the viewport . Would be grateful for any guidance:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        


        .card {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 20%;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #3498db;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            position: relative;
           
            transition: top 1s ease;
         
        }

        #myBox {
            cursor: pointer;
        
            /* Show pointer cursor on hover */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John E</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John F</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" id="myBox" onclick="moveBox()">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John G</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John H</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>



    <script>
        function moveBox() {
            const box = document.getElementById('myBox');

            // Move the box to the top of the screen
            box.style.position = 'absolute';
            box.style.top = '0';

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>




What have you tried? Where are stuck? There seems to be already a lot of questions about smooth transitions here on SO. - [ask] - How to create a [mre]

Could you check the snippet as it isn't showing the problem you describe (the card does not move).

have modified the code to show one which moves. Candidly I have many versions. Really appreciate any help !!

What exactly do you want to happen? Your snippet removes the element from the normal  low and in positioning it absolute it ends up over the top of John E. Do you want instead to change the order of the elements so that John G is the first one, and all the others will be seen after it?

So, you said move the card to the top of the viewport, that could mean a few things (position the element absolute and move the element, scroll the viewport to the element). This scrolls to the card. Is this what you're looking for ?
function moveBox() {
    const box = document.getElementById('myBox');
    // get the position of the element
    const bounding = box.getBoundingClientRect()
    window.scrollTo({
      top: bounding.y + window.scrollY,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    })
}

MDN - getClientBoundingRect()
MDN - sceollTo()
SO - JavaScript getBoundingClientRect() changes while scrolling


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        /* Center the box initially */
        body {}

        .container {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 10%;
        }

        .card {
            width: 100px;
            height: 200px;
            margin-top: 5%;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #3498db;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            position: relative;
            /* Ensure proper positioning */
            transition: margin-top 5s ease;
            /* Add transition effect */
        }

        #myBox {
            cursor: pointer;
            /* Show pointer cursor on hover */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John E</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John F</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" id="myBox" onclick="moveBox()">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John G</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John H</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        function moveBox() {
            const box = document.getElementById('myBox');
            const bounding = box.getBoundingClientRect()
            window.scrollTo({
              top: bounding.y + window.scrollY,
              left: 0,
              behavior: "smooth",
            })


        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>




thanks - but when running this revised code in a full screen the card doesn't seem to move to the top of the page. Would there be a way to address this? Ever so grateful. cheers

To answer your question,  - absolute positioning will be preferable. thanks

@user1665695 In full screen there's no viewport to scroll, because everything fits. If you want to position the card absolutely, what happens to the other cards, what if you scroll, do you revert the absolute position ? what if there's another card in view, do you want to just swap the cards, you need to be more specific.

the other cards would be style.display='none'

I have modified the code to show where movement is instantaneous. not sure why it is so fast - apologies for my beginner questions.
